# In C++ use a C bitmask (anonymous enum) exposed by iOS native library

Tags: c++, c, cocoa, objective-c++, bitmask

Cocoa utilises typedef-ed anonymous enum bitfields.

I'm using objective-C++, for better & worse. Inside a .mm file I need to assign 2 bits (bitwise inclusive OR) to a property of the type of one of these enum bitfield types. The libc++ compiler won't have it because it won't give an rvalue of type int to a property of that  typedef-ed anonymous enum bitfield.

I understand there is a size difference of enums between C & C++. So what is the work-around for this situation?

My line performing the assignment is akin to:

```
    uiSwipeRightDownRecogniser.direction = Right | Down;
```

The definition of the bitfield is akin to:

```
    typedef enum 
    {
        Right = 1 << 0,
        Left  = 1 << 1,
        Up    = 1 << 2,
        Down  = 1 << 3
    } UISwipeDirection;
```

The error is:

*Cannot initialize a parameter of type 'UISwipeDirection' with an rvalue of type 'int'*

That kind of assignment works in a *.m* file, but not a *.mm*.

The compiler is Apple's LLVM 3.0 (using libc++).

Comment: Please post a code example and the error from gcc.

Comment: @ChrisF Could you explain why you’ve voted to close this question **after** the asker provided relevant information?

Comment: @ChrisF Not to pick on you particularly out of all the people who voted to close this, but this is absolutely a real question. Had this exact problem when converting some of my *.m* files to *.mm* files.

Answer (score 1):

Just convert it using `static_cast`:

```
uiSwipeRightDownRecogniser.direction = static_cast<UISwipeDirection>(Right | Down);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works of course. I had seen the casting before but had seen other things that lead me to believe it was not really safe. On a scale of 1 - 10, how safe am I doing the cast?

Comment: @codey this conversion is fine. there is no loss/narrowing. it's analogous to `(UISwipeDirection)(Right | Down)` in C.

Comment: @justin Wondering if you can refer me to data as to why this is? Your solution worked perfectly, but I'm wondering why it was necessary when I was assigning a clearly typed value (one of the enum bitmask values) to something typed as the enum bitmask. Confusing-much.

Comment: @MattMc most C is valid C++, but not this. in C++, the arithmetic operation results in an `int`. in C++, an `int` is not implicitly convertible to an `enum` type. thus, the explicit conversion is required (e.g. `static_cast<>`). this is stronger typing, which prevents you from saying `UISwipeDirection  dir = -2;`. overloading the operators is permitted.